# How to export correctly mesh and armature of a character from blender to NUKE

Tags: export, file-format, .fbx, collada, alembic

I'm looking for a working way to **export** correctly a **rigged character** from blender to **NUKE 11**. I've tried a lot of formats,like :

**ALEMBIC** : it worked partially. It means that the **mesh** is exported correctly to NUKE,but **without** the **armature.**

**FBX** : NUKE crashes everytime if I use **FBX 6.1 ASCII**. Instead,when if I use **FBX 7.4 Binary** mesh AND armature are not imported at all. Maybe the mesh and the armature should be configured in some specific way in blender ?

**DAE** : NUKE says that this **format is not readable**.

So,what ? thanks.

Comment: Download Autodesks FBX Converter, which is a free utility.

Comment: Sorry: https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives        See if converting Blender's FBX output into a newer (or older) version helps. I am not sure that is the fix, but I have used the converter in the past to assist with compatibility issues.

Comment: I tried but it does not work : when in NUKE I import the FBX file converted,I see no mesh and no armature.

Comment: Are you using Nuke 10? 11 is supposed to be 2017 FBX compliant...

Comment: And fyi: https://openvisualfx.com/2017/04/04/exporting-a-blender-scene-to-nuke/

Comment: And now you know everything about Blender to Nuke that I know! :)

Comment: in the link that u gave to me there is no object with armature embedded...

Comment: I'm using NUKE 11...